# How to safely expose one wire of an AC mains circuit?

Tags: mosfet, switches, mains

I need to use a rail to connect one moving piece where a switch is, to a fixed piece where a power tool is. The rail is exposed, so I need this connection to be safe, like 12V or below. I'm guessing I will need some sort of MOSFET module, but each and every search result is about Arduino. Is there such a thing, that will let me use small wires and switches in a "safe" exposed circuit to turn on and off a mains powered device?

Comment: A relay sounds like a better fit, but I've no idea what you mean by moving and fixed 'pieces' here.

Comment: Do you know about opto-interruptors? They're a common solution to detecting the position of a moving device, without having to expose any circuit voltages.

Answer (score 3):

I'd even go further than what Graham Nye says, and look at mains-rated (UL-Listed, not RU-Recognized) relays, contactors etc. designed to attach directly to AC mains wiring methods and provide low voltage terminals with separation.

An example is Aube relays, which are designed to mount in AC mains enclosures (e.g. a junction box and standard 1/2" knockout). They are designed to keep mains on the mains side, and low voltage on the low voltage side. They have a built in transformer, so operating the relay is as simple as shorting two terminals (which have 24VAC on them). That connects the transformer to the relay coil, which picks up the relay.

Now it's not necessary to handle mains at all (except in Electrical Code approved enclosures), and all your work is being done on the low voltage side.   They make other relays, such as **RiB**, with coil voltages of your choice if you want to supply coil power.

Answer (score 1):

Look up solid state relay for a ready-made mains switching block that can be controlled by a low voltage. Or you could use a traditional electromagnetic relay with a low voltage operating coil.

You can stop words appearing in search results by preceding them with a hyphen ("minus"). So -arduino should clean up your search results. However for safety I suggest you don't try making your own MOSFET switch but get a solid state relay instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how, using a 12V= Relay.

[image]